# Python mechanize: Submitting a form with a file (image)?

Tags: python, image, browser, mechanize

There's a form with the following control (it's an upload image control)

```
<FileControl(profile_image=<No files added>)>
```

What am I supposed put in the "??????????":

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(mywebsite)
br.select_form(nr=1)
br.form['profile_image'] = ??????????
br.submit()
```

I've tried

```
   br.form['profile_image'] = open("img.jpg")
```

but get the error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mechanize-0.2.4-py2.6.egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 2784, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: value attribute is readonly
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
br.form.add_file(open(FILENAME), 'text/plain', FILENAME)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
```